# Magento 2 DHL Shipping Method is not working into the Different store view

Tags: shipping, multistore, stores, magento2.3.3, dhl

I have configured the DHL Shipping into the Website (Magento 2.3.3).

The website has 3 store view. All the stores have the same configuration as the DHL Shipping Method. In the Main Store, DHL Shipping is working great.

But into another 2 stores, it is not working. I have checked the shipping log. The request is generated and also get the response from the DHL Server. But in the checkout page no shipping rates are displayed.

Please check the below screenshot:

[image]

Can you please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. Response is coming from the DHL service, but on the cart and checkout pages I get the message "Shipping method is not available"..